# accumulation in R by row

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to do a simple accumulation model in R. Very simple to do in excel,  but of course i need to do it for about 1000 data sets so i would like to code it in R.

Simply put the model is for accumulating and melting snow. The result should be in the 'pack' column. Which should just be previous days pack + snow - melt. Any thoughts on the best way to call the previous days pack? (should initiate with 0 snowpack on day 1)

The second problem is that pack cannot be negative, so on days when it melts but there is no accumulated snow, the pack should stay at 0.

```
df <- read.csv(file = "ddf_mod.csv", header = TRUE)
> df
   day snow melt pack
1    1    0    6    0
2    2    0    2    0
3    3    0    8    0
4    4    0    2    0
5    5    2    0    2
6    6    3    0    5
7    7    4    0    9
8    8    5    0   14
9    9    0    5    9
10  10    0    6    3
11  11    0    3    0
12  12    5    0    5
13  13    8    0   13
14  14    1    0   14
15  15    3    0   17
16  16    0    0   17
```

Answer (score 1):

The part where it can't be below 0 makes this a bit trickier than normal, but you can accomplish this stepwise calculation with `Reduce()`. For example

```
new_melt <- Reduce(function(prev, change) {
     max(prev + change$snow - change$melt, 0)
  }, 
  split(df[c("snow","melt")], seq.int(nrow(df))), 
  init=0,
  accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
```

Here we split the snow/melt values into a list of pairs of observations using `split()` and then we iterate over them. Each time taking the previous value, adding snow, removing melt, and using `max()` to make sure it never goes below 0. (We then remove the initial value with `[-1]`).  Can can merge this new value with the original data to see that it gives what you want

```
cbind(df, new_melt)
#    day snow melt pack new_melt
# 1    1    0    6    0        0
# 2    2    0    2    0        0
# 3    3    0    8    0        0
# 4    4    0    2    0        0
# 5    5    2    0    2        2
# 6    6    3    0    5        5
# 7    7    4    0    9        9
# 8    8    5    0   14       14
# 9    9    0    5    9        9
# 10  10    0    6    3        3
# 11  11    0    3    0        0
# 12  12    5    0    5        5
# 13  13    8    0   13       13
# 14  14    1    0   14       14
# 15  15    3    0   17       17
# 16  16    0    0   17       17
```

Comment: Simpler: `df$new_melt <- Reduce(function(x, y) max(x+y, 0), df$snow - df$melt, accumulate=TRUE, init=0)[-1]`

Comment: Thanks looks great! What is the best way to identify the "prev" term in the function?

Comment: Reduce takes a two parameter function, one for the value from the previous iteration, and one for the "current" value. Here we initialize the first prev to be zero with `init=0`.